# Changing string based on string contents; (NSExpression decimal issue). Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using the `NSExpression` function to evaluate strings as a numerical equation.

One problem that I have encountered is; when you have a division "/" operation in the string you are calculating `NSExpression` does not convert the answer into a float point (double) unless a decimal value is given.

Ex. ( 1.0 / 2 ) = 0.5

But ( 1 / 2 ) = 0

I wonder if there is a simple solution to this problem or if I would have to write a loop that inserts ".0" when it detects a division with no other decimals.

I have tried making a loop like this with little success, so if there is a better solution or someone has a loop structure to solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Usage)? From what I found it does a lot of work for you...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but could I use that in my app, and release it to the AppStore for 0.99? Isn't it copyright?

Comment: According to the license you'd have to include the LICENSE file.

Comment: So I would have to include the License File in my app, available for the user to see swell?

Comment: I think you only have to include it with your own license, inside your app folder for example. But probably I'm not the best person to tell you about that. Why don't you contact the author?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I contacted the author of the app, and I have implemented the software into my program. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

How about, if you detect the presence of slash, cast your expression like this:

```
myExpressionStr = [[@"(double)(" stringByAppendingString:myExpressionStr] stringByAppendingString:@")"];
```

Comment: I should have mentioned:  untested suggestion.